# How to create a user from the macOS command line

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal

I want to know how to create a user account from the macOS command line.

If I try to use the well known `dscl . -create /Users/blah...` it doesn't work.

Also if you type `dscl` the output is like

```
Entering interactive mode...
 >
```

I am also still trying to figure out the `-auth` and `-authonly` part too.

Comment: I edited your question to remove your references to bash. You're struggling with the `dscl` tool, not `bash`. It would help if you'd show exactly what you entered and what result you got. Also, you might be able to skip the `-auth` stuff if you use `sudo` to run `dscl` as the superuser.

Answer (score 8):

There are a few steps to create a user account from the command line. The good news is that you're using the right tool, `dscl`. What you're missing are the separate components that comprise a user account. You have to create these manually.

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/someuser
sudo dscl . -create /Users/someuser UserShell /bin/bash
sudo dscl . -create /Users/someuser RealName "Lucius Q. User"
sudo dscl . -create /Users/someuser UniqueID "1010"  #use something not already in use
sudo dscl . -create /Users/someuser PrimaryGroupID 80
sudo dscl . -create /Users/someuser NFSHomeDirectory /Users/soemuser
```

You can then use `passwd` to change the user's password, **or use**:

```
sudo dscl . -passwd /Users/someuser password
```

You'll also have to create the user's home directory and change ownership so the user can access it. And be sure that the UniqueID is, in fact, unique.

This line will add the user to the administrator's group:

```
sudo dscl . -append /Groups/admin GroupMembership someuser
```

Comment: I understand and have tried using this before but it says something like '-crwate bad key path or something

Comment: If you can give a more precise error description, we may be able to figure this out

Comment: the output is `create: Invalid Path`

Comment: Which command of the ones above threw the error? And what version of OSX and `dscl` are you running?

Comment: Also, did you run the commands as root or as a regular user? Try using `sudo` before the commands. I changed the answer above to show `sudo` usage

Comment: SaxDaddy, all of the -create commands